# How to create 7 day countdown timer?

Tags: python, tkinter, timer

Does anyone know how to make a 7 day timer and have the remaining time left also being displayed?
I have tried using the `.after` method however that uses  ms as units which I don't think is suitable for timers as long as 7 days.

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54700710/how-to-get-the-countdown-date-to-display-correctly-using-python-3

Comment: Using milliseconds should be fine, even for long periods.

Comment: do you know how i could display the 7 day timer?

Comment: There are *many* questions here about displaying a timer with `tkinter`. For this I would probably use `after()` to update the counter at a set rate, i.e. once a second, minute, or whatever, and then manually decrement the countdown value each time that was done to see if it's time to quit (or sound an alarm, display a notification, or whathaveyou).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way but it is not that efficient and that is using `time.sleep()` what this would do is wait a certain amount of time before running a command for example you could do

```
import time
while True:
   print("Hello World")
   time.sleep(604800) #the number of seconds in a week
```

Then to print the second you could do

```
import time
print ('tasks done, now sleeping for 10 seconds')
for i in range(604800,0,-1):
    time.sleep(1)
    print (i)
```

This will print the seconds left